# I need to convert jQuery code to Mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

I need to convert this code from jQuery to MooTools, but I need to admit how I'm not so familiar with Mootools, so every kind of help will be appreciated.

```
($)( document ).ready(function() {
        ($)('.breadcrumbs').prependTo('#main');
        var setWidth = ($)('.column.dynamic.content.ajaxbim').outerWidth();
        ($)(".header .dynamic").css({
            "min-width": setWidth,
            "max-width": setWidth
        });
        ($)(function () {
            ($)('.box_menu_title').tooltip();
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can help with the conversion to Mootools. Please post what you have (HTML & jQuery) in a jsFiddle and post back here.

Answer (score 0):

As I asked you in the comments, please post your HTML so you can get a proper answer.
**Meanwhile here are some pointers:**

Instead of `.ready()` you can use `window.addEvent('domready', function(){`

Intead of prependTO, try with [**inject()**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3ainject) `myThirdElement.inject(mySecondElement, 'top');`

Instead of `.css({` try setStyles:

```
$('myElement').setStyles({
    "min-width": setWidth,
    "max-width": setWidth
});
```

Instead of `.outerWidth();` try **[getSize()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element%3agetSize)**

About the tooltip there is a Class [in mootools More](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Tips) for that.